# Audio duplicate finder - find duplicate audio files regardless of different formats or bitrates

Tags: windows, gratis, audio

Looking for freeware or open source software for Windows that can analyze audio files to determine if it is a duplicate of another audio file regardless of file format (mp3 vs. m4a vs. flac) and bitrates (128kbps vs. 320kbps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a program specific to music (and bonus, images)!

http://www.similarityapp.com/

I used the program to compare music encoded in different formats (flac, m4a, mp3, wma, wav). A duplicate file finder really shows their limitation when the encoded formats or metadata makes the likelihood of finding duplicate music files impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you 2 softwares :

1. [Auslogics Duplicate File Finder](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/duplicate-file-finder/). Its a small program to find duplicate files in your system including images, audio, video and other personal files.
2. [Tune Up Utilities 2014](http://www.tune-up.com/download/). Actually it is a PC optimization tool. But it has a duplicate file finder tool in it.

I had used both many times and both are good.

Comment: I found a software called similarity which is more what I was looking for. Auslogics when I checked in oct 2014 asked you to install malware with their installer.

Comment: Duplicate finders most likely will only compare raw file data instead of analyzing its contents and decoding it by bitrate/codec/whatever.